# Power for hierarchical loglinear model

Tags: sample-size, statistical-power, frequency, log-linear

Can anyone point me in the right direction for doing sample size/power calculations for hierarchical log-linear analysis of nominal (frequencies) data? Would I get in trouble with reviewers for just using the old rule-of-thumb to get 100 cases per cell?